# Nav2 Custom planner plugin does not exist

Tags: ros-humble, nav2, global-planner

I followed this nav2 getting started [guide](https://navigation.ros.org/getting_started/index.html) without issue: I am now following this nav2 custom planner plugin [tutorial](https://navigation.ros.org/plugin_tutorials/docs/writing_new_nav2planner_plugin.html)

I have created a new plugin nav2_straightline_planner in my ws/src directory. And I have confirmed there are no typos between the sample code and mine. When trying to run

$ ros2 launch nav2_bringup tb3_simulation_launch.py params_file:=/ws/src/navigation2_tutorials/nav2_straightline_planner/nav2_params.yaml

I get the following error:

Failed to create global planner. Exception: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class nav2_straightline_planner/StraightLine with base class type nav2_core::GlobalPlanner does not exist. Declared types are  nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner

I have checked my CMAKELists has  `pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file(nav2_core global_planner_plugin.xml)`

my global_planner_plugin.xml is the following

```
<library path="nav2_straightline_planner">
    <class name="nav2_straightline_planner/StraightLine" type="nav2_straightline_planner::StraightLine" base_class_type="nav2_core::GlobalPlanner">
      <description>This is an example plugin which produces straight path.</description>
    </class>
</library>
```

And in my params.xml I have the following:

```
 planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    plugins: ["GridBased"]
    use_sim_time: True
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_straightline_planner/StraightLine"
      interpolation_resolution: 0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you re-source your workspace's install directory?